# Proving that $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) \;\mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a - x) \;\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

The question I have is:

Prove that

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \; \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a - x) \; \mathrm dx$

Since this question occurs at the end of an exercise on integration by substitution, my approach was as follows:

$\displaystyle \text{RTP: } \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \; \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a - x) \; dx \\[12pt]
\displaystyle \text{RHS} = \int_{0}^{a} f(a - x) \;\mathrm  dx \\[12pt]
\text{Let } a - x = u,\ x = a - u \\[12pt]
\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm du} = -1,\ \mathrm dx = -\mathrm du \\[12pt]
\text{When } x = a,\ u = 0, \text{ when } x = 0,\ u = a \\[12pt]
\begin{array}{lll}
\text{Then: RHS} & = & \displaystyle -\int_{a}^{0} f(u) \; \mathrm du \\[12pt]
& = & \displaystyle \int_{0}^{a} f(u) \;\mathrm du = \text{LHS, as reqd.}
\end{array}$

This seems to work well, but my problem is, firstly, that I don't know whether or not I'm right and, more importantly, I don't really understand what I've done. I just applied a technique I've been practising.

What I'm asking of you, then, apart from whether I am correct, is how this proof (or the correct proof) actually works.

Why can I do what I've done? If, indeed, I can do what I've done!

Comment: The argument is fine. In terms of intuition, the curve $y=f(a-x)$ between $0$ and $a$ is the curve $y=f(x)$ reflected in the line $x=a/2$ so the "areas" are the same. If you are worried about the validity of substitution for general definite integrals, there is a theorem that may not have been proved in your course that does it. If we can assume $f$ is continuous, then instead we can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Why is it that I'm allowed to exchange $x$ and $u$ so freely at the end?

Comment: The name of the "dummy" variable of integration is irrelevant in a definite integral.

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. After doing a formal manipulation, it is a very good thing to look back and ask what is really going on. Well, thinking about it before calculating is good too. Here we are basically using symmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you simply applied the change of variables theorem. Let $h(x) = a-x$. The function is invertible and its derivative is always non zero (it's a diffeomorphism). Also note that $h^{-1} = h$. Let's call $I = [0,a]$, then $h^{-1}([0,a]) = [0,a]$

Your problem is thus only an application of the [change of variables theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html) :

$$ \int_I f(x) \ dx = \int_{h^{-1}(I)} f(h(x))\ |h'(x)|\ dx $$

In fact:

$$ \int_{[0,a]} f(x) \ dx = \int_{[0,a]} f(a-x)\ |-1|\ dx = \int_0^a f(a-x)\ dx $$

EDIT:

What you've done is correct, the only difference that you worked with segment orientation, whereas I used a result generalized to greater dimension. So you invert the segment orientation but you don't have absolute value, so you have a minus sign that revert the segment orientation.

This property you just prove is called the translation invariance of Riemann integral